# Gmate installation issue

Tags: gedit, ruby

I was following the link [`GMate`](https://github.com/gmate/gmate) and [`Using Gedit as a Ruby IDE`](http://kibyegon.wordpress.com/2011/11/15/using-gedit-as-a-ruby-ide/) to make my Gedit as IDE. But when all the command was running good,the below one throwing me an error.

```
kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~$ sudo apt-get install gedit-gmate
[sudo] password for kirti: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gedit-gmate
kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~$
```

Help me to fix the issue.

Comment: which version of Ubuntu are you using ,details would help

Comment: @tijybba ubuntu13.10 i am using.

Comment: As far as [released version](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-on-rails/+archive/ppa) goes ,GMate for 13.04 is not yet listed

Answer (score 1):

To install GMate, you have first to add the right PPA.  To do so, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-on-rails/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Once that is done. then you can run:

```
sudo apt-get install gedit-gmate
```

See image below:

[image]
[image]

Comment: yes,I did follow,the same way.

Comment: Just tried it on 13.04, and it worked OK.

Comment: why then I am getting error? should I perform those steps again?

Comment: Before you do try `sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get update`

Comment: I did,still the error `E: Unable to locate package gedit-gmate`.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: then what step I need to perform?

Comment: Then do the installation as in the answer.

Comment: no improvement,still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288459/gmate-install-fail) is not an elegant solution but it worked for me. Replace 'raring' with 'quantal' in the following file and try again:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-on-rails-ppa-raring.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gedit-gmate
```