# Gmate Install Fail

Tags: 64-bit, 13.04, gedit, ruby

I'm looking to install gmate to allow use of gedit for Ruby development.  Currently I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 x64.

I can add the required repository but when I "apt-get update" the following error is given:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-on-rails/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-on-rails/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/q/287116/63025

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, this repository  [does not](http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-on-rails/ppa/ubuntu/dists/) contain any packages for Raring Ringtail yet.

Comment: You can:

A. Wait.

B. Build own version from sources.

C. Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-on-rails-ppa-raring.list` and replace `raring` with `quantal` to install old version. I'm not sure this is best solution - be careful with dependencies.